# Open Dialog Window in Javascript using AngularJS and LumX

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog, window, lumx

I'm making a web application using Javascript and AngularJS. For my user interface I'm experimenting with LumX.

In their site there is an example for a "open dialog box" functionality. Here it is: http://ui.lumapps.com/components/dialog

However, I can't seem to make it work on my application. When I press the "Open Dialog" button, it does nothing. It works on their site, but when I use that code in my program it doesn't work. I know I have all the correct included files because all other LumX features work fine. This is the only one that I've tried that doesn't work.

So can someone give this example a go and see if you can get it to work, and then post your full code here? I must be doing something wrong.

Thank you so much.

Comment: please add you code to check,

Comment: @oriaj - Sorry about the delay. The HTML code I just copied as it was there, I just added the controller `ng-controller="DialogController"`. The JS code I also copied 99% of it, I just wrote `KBTM_App.controller('DialogController', DialogController); DialogController.$inject = ['LxDialogService'];` at the beginning and I deleted the `$scopes` and the notifications.